# How to add a custom Module-Description Variable in Android.mk?

Tags: android-build, android.mk, android-buildconfig

I want to access a module description variable (a custom variable) while building an android module i.e. an executable or shared-library or prebuilt and based on its value do some extra processing on the executable or shared-lib or prebuilt.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Would `LOCAL_CFLAGS` suffice? You could add a custom define (e.g. `LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DFOO`) to your preprocessor.

Comment: Yeah I could do that, but i chose to create a new module description variable, the only catch is i need to add the variable to the list of variables in clear_vars.mk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the variable to the list of variables in `clear_vars.mk` , so that they get cleared when an `Android.mk` does `include $(CLEAR_VARS)`